# Is it safe to call componentWillReceiveProps() with side effects

Tags: reactjs

In React's componentWillReceiveProps function, if I check whether the props have changed first, is it ok to then make an AJAX call?  It seems that this function may be called multiple times in React Fiber (post 16 beta) and this blog (https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d) suggests that no side effects should be performed.  However, I didn't see such a warning in the React docs and I figured that the AJAX call was made only if the props changed that that would be OK.

Comment: Why not do the ajax call in `componentDidUpdate` then?

Comment: @xDreamCoding, I'm working with this Redux example https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/containers/App.js.  I'm guessing that this was done because there was no need to work with any of the DOM nodes, so the AJAX call is being made as early as possible, and dispatch is called when the response comes back, at which point the re-rending occurs.

Comment: I think you can trust into the examples of a repo with core contributors of the reactjs team. So what they are doing there should be considered best practices, no? I just doubt you could get a better answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @xDreamCoding, well, sometimes documentation isn't kept up to date with recent releases, but that's probably not as likely with a project such as React. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to recent (React 16.3+) documentation, this is considered unsafe and in reply to your exact query:

> Using this lifecycle method often leads to bugs and inconsistencies,
>   and for that reason it is going to be deprecated in the future.
>
> If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an
>   animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate
>   lifecycle instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to make a call in OnWillReceiveProps but it's up to you to define a condition that makes sense, if your condition is well made you should not have a lot of call. Anyway you should in most of case avoid the use of OnWillReceiveProps which is kind of greedy in term of perfomance